# No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext arg0]

Tags: java, junit, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am trying to write a test case for vertx related stuff.

Here is my code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MyJUnitTest {

static Vertx vertx;
static HttpServer server;

@BeforeAll
public static void before(TestContext context) {
    Async async = context.async();
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    server = vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("foo")).listen(8080,
            context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    System.out.println("Service started....");
    async.complete();
}

@AfterAll
public static void after(TestContext context) {
    vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@Test
public void test1(TestContext context) {
    // Send a request and get a response
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
    Async async = context.async();
    client.getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", resp -> {
        resp.bodyHandler(body -> {
            context.assertEquals("foo", body.toString());
            client.close();
            async.complete();
        });
    });
}}
```

Getting following error:

> org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext arg0] in executable [public static void remoteprocess.java.samples.MyJUnitTest.before(io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext)].
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:191)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:116)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:228)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassTestDescriptor.java:227)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:151)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:61)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:80)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>       Suppressed: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext arg0] in executable [public static void remoteprocess.java.samples.MyJUnitTest.after(io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext)].
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:191)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:116)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$null$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:242)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:241)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllMethods(ClassTestDescriptor.java:241)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:162)
>           at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:61)
>           at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:96)
>           ... 27 more

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: There are a fair number of hits for that exception text. Tell us what research you have done.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am very new to vertx and learnt JUnit recently. As part of my test case, I am trying to start a server and read the response.

Comment: You can try debugging into your test. You can try researching over on https://github.com/junit-team/junit5 or https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-junit5 (e.g., https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-junit5/pull/34)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not "wrapping" the text with vertx info.

Please, check the documentation:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-junit5/java/#_integration_with_junit_5

Also you should use the annotation `@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)` instead of `RunWith()` to use that parameter in your methods.